# How would I make a basic alert?

Tags: android

I have a `if then` statement. If the `if then` statement is true, I want an Android system to fire a basic alert with one button that says ok.

I have done plenty of research, but nothing works.

Comment: WHat do you mean you have an if statement?  Are you looking to check one  time and then fire off an AlertDialog?  Or are you wishing to be notified when a condition becomes true (which isn't directly possible in a general sense, but depending on what you're checking you may be able to do it)?

Comment: ... just fire a toast?

Comment: Could you be more precise ? What is this if-then you are talking about (as pointed by Gabe Sechan) ? What do you call an alert ? a Toast, or an android-Alert ? What does not work ? You got error ? What i've you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

this is how you create Alert in android

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Write your message here.");
builder.setNeutralButton(
    "Ok",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
builder.create().show()
```

Comment: What context should I use for it?

Comment: Also, `builder.create().show()`, I received a alert saying that CAN NOT RESOLVE SYMBOL BUILDER

Comment: try it now @BobMcregger